# Proving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$ iff $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=a=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\quad\iff\quad\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=a=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}$$

I try to prove this using $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, there exist N, when n > N ,$|a_n - a|< \varepsilon$

how to prove it from right side to left side?

There is my proof:
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\iff\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=a=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}$
$\because\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a,\exists N,n>N,|a_n-a|<\varepsilon\implies N=\frac{2}{\varepsilon},|a_{2n}-a|<\varepsilon,N=\frac{2}{\varepsilon}+1,|a_{2n+1}-a|<\varepsilon$
$\therefore\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\iff\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=a=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}$

$N=max\{2N,2(N+1)\},|a_{2n}-a|<\varepsilon,|a_{2n+1}-a|<\varepsilon\implies |a_n-a|<\varepsilon$

If there is some sub-sequences,a part sub-sequences if converage, can I get a output the the sequence is converage.

Try to prove a sequence all sub-squence is converage that mother sequence is converage can solve it. Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from left to right:

Assume $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=a$. Then $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that whenever $n>N$ then $|x_n-a|<\epsilon.$

Then with the same $N$ we also have $|x_{2n}-a|<\epsilon$ $|x_{2n+1}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$ simply because $2n\geq n$ and $2n+1\geq n$.

Going from right to left. Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that

$|x_{2n}-a|<\epsilon$ when $n>N_1$ and $|x_{2n+1}-a|<\epsilon$ when $n>N_2$.

Then we can pick $N=2\times max(N_1,N_2)+1$ then whenever $n>N$ we have $2$ cases, either $n$ is odd or $n$ is even. Each case satisfies $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ simply due to our choice of N.

Comment: That is right answer I want! By the way how to proof by contradiction. If i asuume $x_n$ and $x_{2n+1}$ limits is not as same as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, how to prove it?

Comment: @Jackin_Q are you still going right to left? and are you assuming these two subsequences converge to different limits or dont converge at all?

Comment: Oof could the downvoter explain why this is downvoted? cheers

Comment: yes, from right to left. I asume two subsquences converage as tow different limits, and prove it was wrong so we accept left $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. That is ChatGPT told me to do that. DOES it Right?  I don't know it was wrong or right.May be wrong & Thanks :)

Comment: Firstly ChatGPT is usually not a great tool to prove mathematical statements correctly. With that being said, if you wanted to prove from right to left then you need to prove the negation of the left statement implies the negation of the right statement. This is considerably more messy